# What is the purpose of the initial parameter in numpy's min / max functions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

According to Numpy's documentation, the initial parameter set's the maximum / minimum value returned by the min or max method. For example:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(x.min(), x.max())
print(x.min(initial=0), x.max(initial=10))
```

What I am wondering is: why would i want to make an initial guess about the maximum or minimum in an array when i am searching for it? What would be a use case where this is necessary?

Comment: have you tried `(numpy.array([]).min()` and `(numpy.array([]).min(initial=10)` ?

Answer (score 1):

As you commented the case for empty array is pretty anecdotic and prone to error.

The main use case is to have a first "base value" for the min/max.

```
>>> np.max(np.array([-1,-2]))
-1
```

while

```
>>> np.max(np.array([-1, -2], O)
0
```

This is especially useful when you have some non-trivial operations and you want to ensure the min/max falls in a range.

```
np.max(x1-x2*x3, O)
```

--> ensures the result will never be negative

The parameter is `initial` because under the hood a reduce operation is used to compute the min/max.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35130718)

Answer (score 0):

As clearly mentioned in the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin)

> initialscalar, optional The maximum value of an output element. Must
> be present to allow computation on empty slice. See reduce for
> details.
>
> New in version 1.15.0.

and

> initialscalar, optional The value with which to start the reduction.
> If the ufunc has no identity or the dtype is object, this defaults to
> None - otherwise it defaults to ufunc.identity. If None is given, the
> first element of the reduction is used, and an error is thrown if the
> reduction is empty.
>
> New in version 1.15.0.

It is quite apparent when you try to determine

```
print(numpy.array([]).min())
```

Which throws the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5f4c7a445299> in <module>
----> 1 print(numpy.array([]).min())
```

But in the case

```
print(numpy.array([]).min(initial=0))
```

we get

```
0.0
```

Comment: That I understood. I'm still wondering why i would want that output - don't we usually wanna know if an array is empty instead of returning a value that does not exist in the array? Even if its part of a larger routine, adding a condition for empty arrays shouldn't be much effort. For me this looks like an invitation for silent errors.